# what file is RSpec currently checking

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

Hi I'm in middle of investigating why when I run specs individually `rspec spec/models/my_model_spec.rb` or just their folders `rspec spec/models/` they work but when I run entire suite `rspec spec` the suit freeze without error

Is there a way to tell rspec to give me output of which file is he currently checking ?

or some other tool that will help me solve this issue ?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default formatter shows just `.`.  you can try using something like

```
  rspec -fd
```

which will cause it to print out the documentation comments

from rspec --help

```
 **** Output ****

-f, --format FORMATTER           Choose a formatter.
                                   [p]rogress (default - dots)
                                   [d]ocumentation (group and example names)
                                   [h]tml
                                   [j]son
                                   custom formatter class name
```

also you might look at adding the `-w, --warnings` flag  to show ruby warnings.  might help.

Answer (score 0):

there is also an option to profile specs  with the -p / --profile flag:

`rspec spec -p`

source: [Rspec extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471586/rspec-extremely-slow)